# How can disrupting carrier signal pinpoint their location?

Tags: the-matrix

In *The Matrix* (1999), Morpheus says to Neo about the red pill:

> Morpheus: The pill you took is part of a trace program.
> It **disrupts your carrier signals so we can pinpoint your location**.

How can disrupting the carrier signal pinpoint their location?

I discovered that carrier signals are used in radios to carry information, but disrupting that will cause noise in radio signals. So enlighten me in Morpheus' concept of pinpointing someone.

Comment: Presumably they're listening to the carrier signals and looking for one that's disrupted

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The carrier signal is a content-free(*) signal onto which an information signal is mapped.  The receiver then subtracts the carrier from the transmitted signal to get the information signal.  Since every one of the billions of people captive of the machines is presumably also transmitting a carrier signal, it alone is not useful in finding Neo.

By imposing changes to a particular carrier signal - which could be by transmitting pulses beyond the normal sideband frequencies, hopping carrier frequencies in a known pattern, altering the carrier frequency to one that is not normally used, etc. - it will make a particular signal stand out from the billions of others *without* having to go to the effort of decoding each captive human's encoded sensorium to look for the one that is hearing what Morpheus and Trinity are saying.

(*)The carrier signal is not technically *completely* content free, since the mere presence of it indicates that something is out there.  If both ends have sufficiently accurate clocks it's also possible to get relative velocity information out of it.

Comment: Not that this isn't likely correct, but can you offer any evidence beyond what's in the film?